# Scripts (DOMContentLoaded) not working in Blazor

Tags: javascript, c#, blazor, .net-8.0, blazor-jsruntime

I have a Blazor Server .NET 8 web application that uses code in the MainLayout to generate a menu (header) depending on the user.
For this menu I need to generate (with JSRuntime)  tags.
Adding the scripts to the page works, but they are not executed.

**I add the scripts by doing this in my App.razor : **

```
function loadScript(url) {
     console.log('loadscript')
     var script = document.createElement('script');
     script.src = url;
     document.head.appendChild(script);
 }

 function addDynamicScript(scriptContent) {
     console.log('addDynamicScript')
     const script = document.createElement('script');
     script.type = 'text/javascript';
     script.innerHTML = scriptContent;
     document.head.appendChild(script);
 }
```

**The first script added is : **
`<script src="domain/url/GetMenu.js"></script>`

**The second uses functions from my first script to populate my menu:**

```
<script>
Document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(event) {GetMenu.SetTopMenuParameters('https://domain.url.com/sso/Theme/0b83be41-32f2-4e8b-8aae-8f03120029af.png', 'Title');
</script>
```

I'm not getting any errors, both scripts are in my HTML source code, it's just not filling my menu.

PS: In razor pages (.cshtml), it works.